# Review page - convert answer to comment

Tags: bug, review, moderator-tools

When converting an answer to a comment from the /review page, it takes you away from the review page, and shows you the post you have just converted to a comment.

It should not do this. It should just collapse the post you have just reviewed (similar to what happens when you close a post), and keep you on the review page.

Comment: This is similar to what reported in [Approving an edit from the review page takes you to the question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112880/approving-an-edit-from-the-review-page-takes-you-to-the-question-page); the action is different, but the effect (being moved to the post you acted upon) is the same.